# ruby read lines which updates latest only from file

Tags: ruby

There is a script which updates the output to a file and planning to setup monitoring of that process and send the latest output information to central server.

For example, the monitoring script will look for the output file for every minute and it has to read only whatever the latest data updated on the output file and send it to central server. Means it should read the old data whatever it read already. Is there any way to make this happen with `ruby version >= 1.8.7`

Here is my scenario,

the script test.sh is running which writes output to file called `/tmp/script_output.txt`

I have another monitoring script `jobmonitor.rb` which is triggered by test.sh and is used to monitor the job status and sends information to central server. Right now it reads the entire contents of `script_output.txt` file and sending the details and it has to send the information for every 2 mins for live monitoring.

Some cases the output file `script_output.txt` will have more than 500 lines, so every 2 mins the monitoring script sending the entire content which includes 2 mins old content as well.

So I am looking way to read the output file content for every 2 mins with the updated content only.

For example:

at present the script_output.txt file has contents,

```
line1
line2
.
.
.
line10
```

and the monitoring script sent these information.

Now after 2 mins the output file has below contents,

```
line1
line2
.
.
.
line10
line11
.
.
.
line 20
```

Now the monitoring script capture all 20 lines and sends the information, instead I need to send the output contents from `line11-20` only.

**Update:**

I tried with below,

```
open(filepath, 'r') do |f|
  while true
    puts "#{f.readline()}"
    sleep 60
  end
end
```

it reads one line only but I want to read the n number of lines which was updated in 120secs or from next line of last read to till now.

Note : I was raised this question already on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446881/ruby-read-lines-from-file-only-latest-updates but I missed to update detailed information initially and so the question was closed. Sorry for that.

Comment: Have you looked at the seek option in Ruby? http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-i-seek

Comment: Yes, I read about that and able to make it work. Thanks for your suggestion!